# What is wrong with my scope alias

Tags: angularjs, scope, alias

http://jsfiddle.net/x3azn/CqkhN/1/

```
Some reason I am getting expression Uundefined function for 

CtrlName as VirtualCtrlName
```

ng-controller should take a function, so how does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Cleaned up version of your example: http://jsfiddle.net/CqkhN/4/</s>

Some points from your code:

- Controller are called as `ng-controller="ControllerName"` (I guess you mixed it up with `ng-repeat="array as arrayItem"`)
- `$scope` should be injected into controller
- `$scope` properties can be accessed in view just by name:

`$scope.foo (in controller) => {{foo}} (in view)`

Consider to complete this short [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) to get better with angular. Good luck ;-)

---

**Edit** @user2167582 I am sorry for my ignorance and misleading answer above, but solution to your issue is pretty simple. As @MarkRajcok said these experimental features are available `with 1.1.5`. So just include the right version in your code 1.1.5 instead of 1.0.6.

Comment: The "ControllerName as alias" is a new syntax available with 1.1.5.  See [John's egghead.io video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTihyXaz4Bo).